# Convert interface{} from JSON to one of multiple concrete types

Tags: go, interface

I've been looking around for a solution to this problem, and couldn't find one here on SO. I'm not sure it's possible, but its worth asking.

I have an interface, and my app reads JSON data from a server. There are few types that might return in response, so I'm using `interface{}` to consume it.

After I've unmarshaled the json bytes to an `interface{}`, how can I convert it to a concrete type? If it fails, I would like to check the next type for conversation, until I have a successful conversation.

It looks something like this (*some code is removed for brevity*)

```golang
type Fooer interface {
    Foo()
}

type A struct { }

func (a *A) Foo() { .. }

type B struct { }

func (b *B) Foo() { .. }

// resp is io.ReadCloser
func heavvyWork(resp) {
    var parsedResp interface{}
    bytesData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp)
    json.Unmarshal(bytesData, parsedResp)

    // convert parsedResp to a concrete type, it might be A or B struct
    // try A, if fails, try B.
    ...
    concreteType.Foo()
}
```

I have looked over *type assertions* and casting, but couldn't get this to work.

Is that possible with Go?

Example for JSON response content

```
A:
{
  "data": {
    "access_key": "AKIA...",
    "secret_key": "xlCs...",
  }
}

B:
{
  "data": {
    "data": {
      "foo": "bar"
    },
    "metadata": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *"how can I convert it to a concrete type?"* -- Manually. Since you're using `interface{}` as the destination for unmarshal, the result will be `map[string]interface{}` or `[]interface{}` or some primitive. So you take your `parsedResp`, type-assert to one of the **possible** types, and then each element, if it has any, and so on... and then from what you gather you build the concrete types. Or just don't use `interface{}` in the first place.

Comment: I'm using `interface{}` to parse a json response. When I tried to type assert it to the A/B structs it failed. Do I need to iterate over each field in the struct? Or the general `t, ok := parsedResp.(A)` should work?

Comment: What struct? `interface{}` is not a struct, doing `json.Unmarshal(data, &dest)` where dest is of type `interface{}` with **no initialized dynamic type** will not magically figure out that you would like `A` or `B`. i.e. there's **no** struct in `parseResp`.

Comment: That's my problem, it can be either A or B. How can I address that? Unmarshal it to a concrete type and iterate my structs (A, B, ..) until unmarshaled successfully?

Comment: That depends on the json data, and the `A` and `B` structs, which there's no info of in your question.

Comment: I've added example of JSON response content

Comment: If you unmarshal into and `interface{}` you will get `map[string]interface{}` for JSON objects. You need to do the conversion from that, or unmarshal into the right concrete type directly.

Comment: So my only option is to cast it to `map[string]interface{}` and iterate the result, try to figure what type is it based on the fields and construct the struct manually?

Comment: @ChenA. yes, if the `data` is as random as you show and you have no way of knowing upfront what concrete type the json bytes represent, then you have to do the ugly thing where you fumble around with `map[string]interface{}`.

Comment: See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsN11YAEJHY&t=403s) for some tips on unmarshaling unknown types.

Comment: @ChenA. in general, when using sensible APIs, you *know* exactly what the data type represented by the json bytes is and you can simply initialize the corresponding concrete type and unmarshal the json into that instead of having to deal with the empty interface. If you're dealing with non-sensible APIs then, consequently, your code will have to deal with nonsense.

Comment: Is there a way to unmarshal the `data` to a `struct`, and fail if it doesn't match the struct completely? i.e, `unmarshal(data, &a)` and if it's not a valid `a` struct, continue with `unmarshal(data, &b)` ..

Comment: Do you know the type for a given response, or is the type arbitrary?

Comment: The type is arbitrary, but to one of the two types; it's either A or B. I'm trying to hide from to user to specify which it is.

Answer (score 1):

You have options.  None of them are exactly wonderful.

One is, as mentioned, to just look inside the map for keys.  I wrote up an example of this [here](https://play.golang.org/p/V2ZSi45fk36).  It's meant to be instructive, but not particularly efficient or anything.

Another is to use `json.RawMessage` to defer parsing a bit.  I wrote up an example of this [here](https://play.golang.org/p/kNPeBnfTRZb).  Note how I resort to pointer members of the various `struct`s in the decoder.  This makes things annoying: you might want to have pointer-ized data types just for the decode, and use non-pointer types once you've picked a type.  But it does let you use more of the json package directly (via struct tags).

Yet another is to use `json.NewDecoder` to get a stream decoder and work through it.  This would probably be the most robust method, but also the trickiest.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed examples. I'm thinking to refactor it. Have a generic struct to parse the json to (like in your 2nd example), and then figuring out which struct is it based on the expected content. Do you have an example of the `json.NewDecoder` ?

Comment: No, the NewDecoder one looked to be the trickiest of all and I just stopped at that point. :-)